# Compensation capacitor(s) in instrumentation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, compensation

I wonder whether the discrete 3-opamp instrumentation amplifier requires any compensation capacitors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEVeZ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is it in general recommended to add compensation capacitor(s)?  For example, in parallel with the RD connecting OA3 output to OA3 inverting input.  What about one in parallel with RF1 and one in parallel with RF2?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic on this site. Per given op-amp or instrumentation amp the datasheet and addendums normally cover such issues in detail, including PCB layout for high performance op-amps. You need to set rational goals, then go shopping via Google.

Comment: No compensation capacitor is added without a well defined reason. They either roll off spurious HF noise or act as a phase shift due to internal phase shifts, so they cancel out.

Comment: However, external compensation will reduce CMRR.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the step-input response, the settling-time, you must have.

Also, if OA3 is not unity-gain-stable, that is a problem.

And if you use Meg Ohm resistors, then with typical opamp and PCB capacitances you can easily have 10KHz f3db points.
The added phaseshifts may convert that 10 usec/channel telemetry system  into an oscillator

Answer (score 1):

No need for Caps using stable Op Amps BUT Rf needs to be 0.1% for only 60dB CMRR.

If you need >100 dB CMRR, use an INA.

The source  Rs*Cs=T1 which you not defined, can be matched to the same product Rf*Cf=T1 for gain matching.

Comment: I am indeed assigning 0.1% resistors for Rf's *and also for the RD's*.  Extra-high CMRR is not critical for my application; mostly, I need a differential amplifier with bandwidth in the tens of MHz and very high input impedance (including very low input capacitance) on each of the inputs.